# Transpose and group sql results

Tags: sql, sql-server, transpose

I need to group and transpose a SQL query

My data looks like this:

```
Titulo    |   Valor
----------+---------
Cartera   |   Valor1
Nombre    |   Valor2
Direccion |   Valor3
Cosa      |   Valor4
Cartera   |   Valor5
Nombre    |   Valor6
Direccion |   Valor7
Cosa      |   Valor8
Cartera   |   Valor9
Nombre    |   Valor10
Direccion |   Valor11
Cosa      |   Valor12
Cartera   |   Valor13
Nombre    |   Valor14
Direccion |   Valor15
Cosa      |   Valor16
```

I would like to group the data according to the "Titulo" column but transpose the information and look like a table.

Example

```
Cartera | Nombre  | Direccion | Cosa
--------+---------+-----------+-------
Valor1  | Valor2  | Valor3    | Valor4
Valor5  | Valor6  | Valor7    | Valor8
Valor9  | Valor10 | Valor11   | Valor12
Valor13 | Valor14 | Valor15   | Valor16
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: How you know `Valor3` in Direccion go to `Valor1` in Cartera?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to pivot your result set:

```
SELECT pvt.Cartera, pvt.Cosa, pvt.Direccion, pvt.Nombre FROM 
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY titulo ORDER BY valor) AS row, titulo,  valor FROM @MyTable) AS dt
PIVOT
(MAX(valor) FOR titulo IN ([Cartera], [Nombre], [Direccion], [Cosa])) AS pvt
```